# Invert image color on click [Android]

Tags: android, image, user-interface, image-processing, onclick

I'm trying to do something like android default alarm clock app. When you click on the clock the icon turns black.

I have seen that there is only one clock image on android, ic_lock_idle_alarm. Then I think that android invert image programmatically.

I don't know how I could to do that.

I tried to set the invert image, created by photoshop with setBackgroundResource but the "black image" overlaps white image.

Otherwise I don't know which is the best approach.

Some advices? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android default alarm clock app does not actually use `ic_lock_idle_alarm` but instead two PNG images from within the app, namely `ic_clock_alarm_on` (the normal icon) and `ic_clock_alarm_selected` (the black version). The black version is activated using `android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"` in a [Drawable State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). This is also how I would recommend you to do it since it is for use cases like this Drawable State Lists exist, and since it is much easier than to do it programmatically.